# Null Point Exception Error with simple card class

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

I'm a beginner with Java, and I've been making test code to apply some of the concepts I read about. So, I wanted to create a class to describe playing cards. The card class contains fields describing both suite and value (1 - 13 for all 4 suites). This class was very simple to create, as you can see --

```
public class Card {
    private String suite; 
    private int cardValue;

    Card(String s, int cV){
    this.suite = s;
    this.cardValue = cV;
    }

    public String getSuite(){
    return this.suite;
    }

    public int getCardValue(){
    return this.cardValue;
    }
}
```

I made another class to test this class, as well as add 52 cards to an array (I have another class that will deal with a 52 card deck, but that's not important in the context of my question here). This class, called `CardTest`, contains the main method. I created a for loop that appends everything to the deck array, however my problems occur when I want to loop through the deck and print out card values (suite and value). I receive a NullPointException error. Here is the cardTest class:

```
public class CardTest {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Card[] temp = new Card[52];
        for (int i = 0; i <12; i++){
            temp[i] = new Card("Spade", i + 1);
            temp[i+13] = new Card("Club", i + 1);
            temp[i+26] = new Card("Diamond", i + 1);
            temp[i +39] = new Card("Heart", i + 1);
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < 52; i++){
            System.out.println(temp[i].getSuite());
        }
    }
}
```

I tried to search for issues regarding this type of error, but the only thing I've gathered is that there is an issue with the Card objects being set to a default "null" value, which yields the error on the method call.

Comment: Are you missing something? The second `for` loop is empty, and what you have is fine.

Comment: Yeah, I just fixed that because I copied from IDE in-between edits without double checking

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your for loop for creating cards is wrong you are only crating 12*4=48 cards, leaving temp[12], temp[25], temp[38] and temp[51] null, try

```
    for (int i = 0; i <13; i++){
        temp[i] = new Card("Spade", i + 1);
        temp[i+13] = new Card("Club", i + 1);
        temp[i+26] = new Card("Diamond", i + 1);
        temp[i +39] = new Card("Heart", i + 1);
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Evidently, you aren't adding 52 `Card` instances to your array (you add 4 for each of 12 iterations, 12 * 4 = 48 != 52). So when you loop over the entire array, some of the values will inevitably be `null` (remember that arrays of objects initially contain only `null`s). Looping until `i < 13` should fix this.

Answer (score 1):

The problem lies here:

```
        temp[i+13] = new Card("Club", i + 1);
```

It will never be 12, which is why you get your nullpointer exception.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you're only filling up the `temp` array up to index 50 (11 + 39), and the second loop tries to access index 51. The upper bound on the first loop should be 13, not 12.